# How to put the max of 3 separate columns in a new column in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

for example we have:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

And now using python I'm trying to create this:

| a | b | c | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 3c |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 4b |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 3a |

Comment: you need to consider that two or more columns could have the same max value. What should be the result in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need match first maximal column join max converted to strings with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for columns names by max:

```
cols = ['a','b','c']
df['max'] = df[cols].max(axis=1).astype(str).str.cat(df[cols].idxmax(axis=1))
print (df)
   a  b  c max
0  1  1  3  3c
1  2  4  1  4b
2  3  2  1  3a
```

If possible multiple max values and need all matched columns use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) trick with separator `,`:

```
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  3  1  3
1  2  4  1
2  3  2  1

cols = ['a','b','c']

max1 = df[cols].max(axis=1)
s = df[cols].eq(max1, axis=0).dot(pd.Index(cols) + ',').str[:-1]
df['max'] = max1.astype(str).str.cat(s)
    
print (df)
   a  b  c   max
0  3  1  3  3a,c
1  2  4  1    4b
2  3  2  1    3a
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this:

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df['max'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: f"{row.max()}{row.idxmax()}", axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

idxmax(axis=1), method returns a Series with the index of the maximum value for each row.

assuming your dataframe is df.

```
df['max'] = df.idxmax(axis =1) + df.max(axis=1).map(str)
```